# Angular 2: Proxy not working when using Http

Tags: angular, proxy, angular2-http

I'm learning Angular 2 atm and am trying to request data from an external server using a proxy. My proxy.conf.json looks like this:

```
{
    "/users": {
        "target": "http://XX.XX.XX.78:4444",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": "true",
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

where the Xs obviously are numbers.

When i navigate directly to localhost:4200/users in my browser (Latest Chrome) the proxy redirect works like a charm - I get the data from the external server displayed. Also in my terminal i see

```
[HPM] GET /users -> http://XX.XX.XX.78:4444
```

Yet, when i try to fetch data via Angulars Http in my service by

```
return this.http
  .get(`/users`)
  .map((r: Response) => r.json().data as String[])
  .catch((error: any) => {
    console.error('An friendly error occurred', error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  });
```

I always get a 404 error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: /users
```

Strangely in my network tab there is no evidence, that a request was made. Also in my terminal, there is no message about redirecting.

Any ideas anyone? I'd be grateful.

Comment: how are you running your application ng serve?

Answer (score 0):

if your proxy than you can't use `ng serve` you should create you own script

you should add new script in the package.json --> scripts

```
"proxyServe": "ng serve -host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --extract-css ",
```

Now run your application `npm run proxyServe`

Comment: doing this using `0.0.0.0` results in the same behaviour (as expected, since in my understanding it should redirect to the default route). Switching `0.0.0.0` to my servers ip gives the following error when trying to compile:
`> ng serve -host http://XX.XX.XX.78:4444 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --extract-css

getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://XX.XX.XX.78:4444
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://XX.XX.XX.78:4444
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)`